# embedded system kill process: Is it safe? Why not?

Tags: kill, embedded

I am designing a networked embedded application, that can span multiple machines. The applications is divided between these machines.

Now, when it comes to exerting explicit control on this system, there are two options:

(1). A nicely managed strategy in which the application nicely releases resources, and goes out. No memory leaks, and it all looks good.

(2). I am facing criticism from people on the managed approach: Why is it not *just as good* to kill the process, in each machine separately? My only defence is that it is not nice, and may leave the system in an unstable state. This argument does not cut with them.

Can anyone please help? I know that *kill* is not the best way, but why? Also, are there some references? I will need to include them in my work.

Sorry, this problem may be discusses ad nauseam, but I cant get any "references" to support my point.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What kind of system is it? I would imagine you'll get radically different answers for killing a process in embedded linux, vs Windows CE...

Comment: Linux. But how would the answer change for Windows?

Comment: The question makes me wonder about things like how well does the OS clean up after killing a process when it has things like bound sockets, file descriptors, shared memory regions, file access operations for settings files, etc. Different OS's will undoubtedly handle those different corner cases differently. Killing the process is going to leave it up to the OS to clean up after the mess you made in the application. I wouldn't recommend it but I also didn't post this as an answer because I didn't do any real research on how well that all works in Linux or Windows. Although I agree with you.

Comment: Okay. Thanks @MarkSmith. Its little hard to believe that this question is one of those, where best practice tells you not to *kill*, but there is no reference, as to why it is such a bad idea.

Comment: If you're willing to step on a few toes, what I would recommend doing is play with it a little. Do devious things like put a sleep in a critical section of the code and see how the application recovers after killing it while it's sleeping and restarting it. I know there's spots in the applications I work on that would absolutely not be acceptable for the process to die. Find a few ways to corrupt the system with ill timed process kills and the proof is in the system itself. When you find 10-15 different plausible places where the system becomes a brick, maybe you'll find people more agreeable.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Let me see how much proof I can muster!

Comment: Actually, my first response to the criticism was "Seriously, WTF?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a few things I did find regarding cleanup of resources with killing the process

[One example](http://www.readmespot.com/question/u/15393/-end-process--equivalent-on-linux)

[Another Example](http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/157/kill-process-with-care/)

[Socket Example](http://www.unix.com/solaris/134310-killing-thread-having-listener-socket.html)

Comment: except the "Socke Example" all other links dead.